# Making particles pile up on the floor

Tags: particles, collision

I have a simple scene. I'm using a particle system but the particles don't collide with the floor. They disappear after reaching the floor. I would like the particle to settle on the floor after being emitted from the top. Any suggestion are appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, after seeing your scene, increase your particles lifetime so they can actually reach the floor.

Then you need to create an actual collision object, because physical objects do only interact with special defined collision objects.

[image]

At deafult settings, the particles are bouncing very heavy after touching the collision object and if you want to change this bounciness you have to go to your collision object and change the stickiness.

And If you want to prevent them from gliding on the floor, increase the friction.

[image: Settings collision object]